# "for" works, why "foreach" dosen't work here in PHP "is Prime" code?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

"for" works, why "foreach" dosen't work here in PHP "is Prime" !

### What is the really mistake? I think they should return same!!

```
    $num = (int) readline("Enter: ");

    $isPrime = "True";

    // foreach (range(2, $num) as $value) {
    for($value=2; $value<$num; $value++){
            if ($num % $value == 0) {
                  $isPrime = "False";
                  break;
            }
    }

    echo $isPrime . "\n";
```

Output with for:
Enter: 23
True

Output with foreach:
Enter: 23
False

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `range(2, $num)`, it will include that number. When you get to `if ($num % $value == 0)`, it's checking `if(23 % 23 == 0)`, which of course evaluates to true. You need to instead make the range one smaller than the number:

```
foreach (range(2, $num - 1) as $value)
```

Comment: If this fixes your issue, mark it as solved by hitting the checkmark, so that others know it helped.